# Is there .NET library for email sending via PROXY?

Tags: c#, email, proxy, smtp

I want to send email via SMTP via proxy on visual studio.
Is there any email sending library which would support proxy ?

Comment: There is no proxy in SMTP protocol. There is only relaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

When you talk about sending via a proxy can you give more detail?

If you mean "how do I send SMTP over an HTTP proxy", you can't. HTTP proxies only support HTTP and HTTPS, although some proxy servers also support FTP, SOCKS, etc but not (as far as I know) SMTP.

There is a such a thing as an SMTP proxy but I don't think they are very common; I think they are all proprietary implementations. I certainly have not seen a C# library to handle such a proxy, and I don't think there is a single standard for this - I've failed to find an RFC (or equivalent document) that specifies the standard.

Instead of using an SMTP proxy, It is more normal to have a "store-and-forward" mail transfer agent (MTA). In other words you would set up a normal MTA, and have this receive emails and forward them on to other MTAs. If this is the case in your setup, there is no special code or libraries required. Just sending your email direct to your local MTA using the SmtpMail class and not worry about the fact it is really acting as a "forwarder"

Comment: HTTP proxy and SOCKS proxy support any underlying protocol including SMTP, IMAP, POP3. So you can connect to SMTP server over HTTP proxy and send emails. -1

Comment: Pawel: you cannot proxy SMTP via and HTTP proxy - it just is not possible. If you have a SOCKS proxy *and* your email client supports SOCKS you may be able to, but the Smtp class in .Net does not, to my knowledge. You could play around with tools such as SocksCap I suppose, but ultimately, I was trying to illustrate that in SMTP it is more normal to have an MTA to "forward" or "proxy" your mail, and not use a traditional proxy at all.

Comment: @ Rob: SOCKS proxies are not required. The HTTP CONNECT method allows you to tunnel pretty much *any* TCP protocol through an HTTP proxy, including SMTP and its variants. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel  So, you *can* send SMTP over an HTTP proxy.  Of course, the sloppy half-baked mess known as .NET doesn't make it exactly easy...

Answer (score 3):

You can try using starksoft proxy (it's free), but it contains several bugs so be careful:
http://www.starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html

You may want to try [Mail.dll email component](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) it supports **HTTP** and **SOCKS** proxies.

Please note that I'm the author of Mail.dll and it's not free.

You can check out how to use proxies with Mail.dll here:

http://www.limilabs.com/blog/imap-pop3-smtp-via-http-socks-proxy

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are referring to a Socks Proxy server.

This is a shameless plug, but since you didn't specify you wanted an open source, or a free library, all of my email components at [www.advancedintellect.com](http://www.advancedintellect.com) have Socks proxy support.