# Sending email over proxy using CDO

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I want to send email from C# winform application, my internet connection uses a proxy.

This is what i have done so far

```
     WebProxy proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Address);
        if (proxy.Address!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage oMsg = new MailMessage();
                // TODO: Replace with sender e-mail address.
                oMsg.From = fromGmailAddress;
                // TODO: Replace with recipient e-mail address.
                oMsg.To = toAddress;
                oMsg.Subject = "Send Using Web Mail";

                // SEND IN HTML FORMAT (comment this line to send plain text).
                oMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

                // HTML Body (remove HTML tags for plain text).
                oMsg.Body = "<HTML><BODY><B>Hello World!</B></BODY></HTML>";
                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", 465);
                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver", "smtp.gmail.com");
                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing", 2);
                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver", proxy.Address.Host);

                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/proxyserverport", proxy.Address.Port);
                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", true);

                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1");
                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", gmailUsername);
                oMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", gmailPassword);

                SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert( 0,"smtp.gmail.com");
                SmtpMail.Send(oMsg);

                oMsg = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }
```

It throws an exception, transport failed to connect to the server.
I have tried 465,587 and 25 for port of Gmail smtp server. Nothing works.

I had been reading over the net about the possibilities that proxy server may not be enabled for email sending. Please correct me if I read or understood wrong? As this proxy allows me to login for gmail account when i use browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I didn't think web proxies typically supported non-HTTP communication. Are you sure you don't want to use a SOCKS proxy here?

Comment: @M.Babcock any link to tutorial to that? How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there .NET library for email sending via PROXY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156753/is-there-net-library-for-email-sending-via-proxy)

Comment: @M.Babcock well i did search on the net whole day, going through answers and answers on stackoverflow and other sites, i did get accross the one you mentioned too. I am not asking for a library that does it. I am asking for ideas that can help achieve my task.

Answer (score 1):

// Use the function below it will work behind proxy even

```
using System.Net.Mail;
public int SendMailUsingGMAIL(string fromAddress, string toAddress, string tocc, string mailsubject, string msgContent, string strAttachment, bool isBodyHTML)
{
    int retvar = 0;
    try
    {

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(fromAddress)
                                            , new MailAddress(toAddress));

        mailMessage.Subject = mailsubject;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHTML;
        mailMessage.Body = msgContent;
        if (tocc != "")
        {
            mailMessage.CC.Add(tocc);
        }
        System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCredentials = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("smtpUserName", "smtpPassword");//key="smtpUserName" value="urid@gmail.com";key="smtpPassword" value="your password"
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = networkCredentials;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        retvar = -1;

    }


    return retvar;

}
```

Comment: what exception did you get plz share!