# How can I send email through proxy server in C#

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0, proxy, smtp

Hi I want to send mail with ASP.NET, 
but I want to send email through proxy server,
So how should I edit the code below to send it through a proxy server?

Thanks

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new  SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"]);
mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAccount"]);
mail.To.Add(toAddres);
mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddress));
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = content;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpServer.Port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPort"] == null ? 587 : int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPort"]);
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPassword"]);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Ok it is done, any suggestion?

Comment: Please refer to [this question and relative accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156753/is-there-net-library-for-email-sending-via-proxy). It explains the SMTP via proxy misunderstanding.